# link to boost:asio in windows 7, NetBeans

Tags: c++, windows, boost, netbeans, boost-asio

i'm trying to build a test case async_tcp_echo_server.cpp in NetBeans, but I did not go.

Code: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

My properties:

```
Project Properties -> C++ Compiler -> Include Directories = C:/boost/boost_1_53_0
Project Properties -> C++ Compiler -> Tool = g++.exe
Project Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories = C:/boost/boost_1_53_0
```

Errors:

```
g++.exe    -c -g -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -I/cygdrive/C/boost/boost_1_53_0 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:138:2: warning: no newline at end of file
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows
g++.exe     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/ub build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o -L/cygdrive/C/boost/boost_1_53_0 
build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o: In function `_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii':
/cygdrive/C/boost/boost_1_53_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/cygdrive/C/boost/boost_1_53_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/cygdrive/C/boost/boost_1_53_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o: In function `_ZN5boost4asio21stream_socket_serviceINS0_2ip3tcpEE16shutdown_serviceEv':
/cygdrive/C/boost/boost_1_53_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x7): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

... etc ...

Comment: Try linking against the Boost.System library.

Comment: where are your boost .a files. Normally `C:\??\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib` not `C:/boost/boost_1_53_0` the same as the include Dir. search for `*boost_system*.a` and put this lib to your project libs properties.